# Connecting remote database in Xamarin Forms for IOS application

Tags: database, winforms, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a project has two parts.

1- Windows form or WPF application that basically connects to database and write/read/update some basic text data (this part is already done).

2- On the other hand, I am currently developing an IOS app that can connect to remote database and read/write/update data.

What is the best way to connect the same SQLite or SQL database from both Windows forms app and IOS app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://github.com/activa/iridium supports all .NET platforms and can connect to SQL Server or a local Sqlite database

Answer (score 1):

The best way is creating an API/WebService which will be the interface between the database and your clients: WPF, iOS App and any other client you might want to add in the future.

Using a WebService is more secure, I guess you wouldn't want your database username and password being everywhere.

Using a WebService allows you abstract the data layer. Not using an API and using the connection to the database directly from your Apps will tightly couple your apps with the structure of your tables and any single change that happens in the database will force you to do the changes in the apps.

With WebService you decide what information will be available to the ones consuming it.

There are many others Plus on using WebServices but hope this are enough to clear your doubt.

Comment: Are there any introductory tutorials, examples about WebServices? The ones that I found are complicated for beginners. Thanks!